# HTML elements breaking link below

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown

I was editing something in the [Chart.js documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/chart.js/topics) (the mcve part) when a link wasn't displayed as it should be in the markdown preview.

While trying to fix this issue, I noticed that the `<hr>` written in the line above was triggering it.
[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otrTY.png) is reproducible on every anchor.

A quick fix is to add a new line between the `<hr>` and the link ([as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEGgd.png)).

This issue seems to exist with several HTML elements (not all of them though) :

- `<hr>`, as stated above.
- `<br>`, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXqCs.png)
- `<h1>`, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhEnt.png). **Note** that the issue is not reproducible with the `<h2>` though.
- `<table>`, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDrYH.png), which, of course, cannot be tested on other SO markdowns editors.
- *... maybe more, I haven't tested them all*

As [*Mike*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332986/html-elements-breaking-link-below?noredirect=1#comment386735_332986) ans [*Squidward*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332986/html-elements-breaking-link-below?noredirect=1#comment386793_332986) said in the comments, all of these HTML elements have markdown equivalents (`# _` for `<h1>_</h1>`, `---` for `<hr>`, etc.).
However, these markdown equivalents [don't seem to trigger the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWq55.png).

---

But I am not looking for making these HTML elements work.

The thing is, since it works with the plain HTML on [other markdown editors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXN0.png) on SO, I wondered if everything is fine about it (*and if I should have expected the result I had in the docs*), or **if it is a bug**.

Comment: Is `<hr>` valid? Shouldn't it be `<hr />`? Hmm based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/158100) I wouldn't say so ... inconsistent it is ...

Comment: @rene The `/` in empty tags was only needed in XHTML - HTML doesn't require it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah, I wasn't sure if the html here was maybe xhtml but that is long gone

Comment: There are markdown equivalents to all of those HTML elements except `<br>`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You'll have to pry my HTML tags from of my cold, dead hands...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Double space?

Comment: @Squidward. I haven't tried.  Might not work in comments...

Comment: @Squidward It doesn't look like that works for `<br>` in Documentation, at least for the preview.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Works for me: `a__\nb` => `a<br>b` (replace `_` with space, comments are broken). Though I'd say that `<br>` should almost never be used. Paragraphs are preffered.

Comment: @Squidward Oh, I get it now. I was thinking just a double space with no newline. I agree about `<br>`, I've been trying to beat it out of my developers for years :).